# Memory address and content

Tags: c, pointers

I have written

```
int a;
printf("addr = %p and content = %x\n", (void*)(&a), *(&a));
printf("addr = %p and content = %x\n", (void*)(&a)+1, *(&a)+1);
```

What I see in the output is

```
addr = 0x7fffffffde3a and content = 55554810
addr = 0x7fffffffde3b and content = 5555
```

I expect to see one byte in each address. However, I don't see such thing. Why?

Comment: Because `&a` is the address of an uninitialized `int`.

Comment: `a` is an integer, which is commonly 4 bytes (use `sizeof()` to be certain). Even after dereferencing the variable's address, its still an int. The `%x` print formatter casts it to an unsigned int, which means it still takes the same number of bytes.

Comment: OK. I understand. That means I have to use 4 instead of 1. How can I break that to bytes?

Comment: I change that to `char a`. Still I see more than one byte as the content.

Comment: Trim the value with a bit mask `a & 0xFF`

Comment: To get the other bytes, shift `a` by 8 bits at a time `(a >> (8 * byteNum)) & 0xFF`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, pointer arithmetic and the dereference operator honors the data type.

Remember, a pointer arithmetic, which generates a pointer one past the last element of an array is valid, but attempt to dereference the generated pointer is undefined behavior.

Attempt to dereference a pointer which points to invalid memory location is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said,

Quoting `C11`,

> The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. [...]  If the operand has type *‘‘pointer to type’’*, the result has type *‘‘type’’*.

So, in your case, `*(&a)` is the same as `a`, which is of type `int`, and the format specifier prints the integer value stored in `a`.

If you want to see the *byte-by-byte* value, you need to cast the pointer (address of `a`) to a `char *` and then, dereference the pointer to see value stored in each byte.

So, `(void*)(&a)+1` should be changed to `(char*)(&a)+1` to point to the next byte of memory.

Comment: With `printf("addr = %p and content = %x\n", (char*)(&a)+i, *((&a)+i));` where `i` is a counter, I see `addr = 0x7fffffffde40 and content = ffffffc0` and then `addr = 0x7fffffffde41 and content = 47`

Comment: Be careful- while a might be of type `int`, the print formatter `%x` will cast it to `unsigned int`.

Comment: @mahmood that's sounds like a value larger than 128 is getting promoted to an int, and sign extension is causing all the preceding bits to become 1s. Then a full 4 bytes is being printed due to the `%x` print formatter. Try changing all `char` to `unsigned char`.

Comment: same results I see

Comment: I don't think the problem is with signed/unsigned char. Thing is that, I want to print a char in hex format. I have the address and I want to print that. So, I have to see `addr = 0x7fffffffde40 and content = ffffffc0` and then addr = `0x7fffffffde41 and content = ff`

Comment: @mahmood did you try using `%hhx` as the format specifier?

Answer (score 0):

You've used the formatting directive `%x`. `%x` expects an `unsigned int`. The type of what you pass as the corresponding argument to `printf` does not change that. `printf` will read an `unsigned int` values from its arguments, no matter what you pass to it. If what you pass something that isn't compatible with what `printf` reads, the behavior of your program is undefined.

You happen to pass an `int`. An `int` is not an `unsigned int`, but it's close enough that when you read an `int` expecting an `unsigned int`, the value remains the same if the integer is positive or zero. Negative integers are mapped to a large positive value (`UINT_MAX - a` on machines using two's complement representation, which is almost all machines).

If you pass a `char` (signed or not) to `printf` when it expects an `int` (signed or not), the behavior is well-defined due to another feature of the C language, which is promotions. Values of integer types that are smaller than `int` (i.e. `char` and `short`) are converted to `int`¹. So the following program snippet is well-defined and prints the value of a byte at the address `p` (assuming that `…` is replaced by a valid pointer value):

```
unsigned char p = …;
printf("addr = %p and content = %x\n", (void*)p, *p);
```

`*(&a)` is the same thing as `a`. To see just one byte of `a`, you could cast the pointer `&a` to the type `unsigned char *`.

```
printf("addr = %p and content = %x\n", (void*)&a, *(unsigned char *)(&a));
```

This will print one byte of the representation of `a` in memory. Note that the representation depends on the machine's [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Your code snippet doesn't initialize `a`, so the first call to `printf` prints whatever garbage happens to be at the location of `a` in memory at this time. This assumes that `int` does not have any [trap representation](https://trust-in-soft.com/trap-representations-and-padding-bits/), which is the case on virtually all C implementations.

The second call to `printf` tries to print `*(&a)+1`. This is just `a+1`. The output you get is surprising: are you sure you didn't actually run the program with `*(&a+1)`? This seems to be what you wanted to explore. With `*(&a+1)`, the behavior of your program would be undefined, because this looks *one `int`* past `a`, and `a` is not in an array of two or more `int`s. In practice, you'd be likely to get whatever was just below `a` on the stack, but that's not something you can count on.

If you wanted to see the byte value at an address which is 1 past the start of `a` in memory, you'd need to cast the pointer to a byte pointer first. When you add an integer *n* to a pointer, this doesn't add *n* to the *address* stored in the pointer, it adds *n* to *the pointer itself*. This is only useful when the pointer points to a value inside an array; then `p + n` points to `n` array elements past `p`. In fact, `p[n]` is equivalent to `*(p+n)`. If you want to add 1 to the address, then you need to obtain a byte pointer, i.e. a pointer to `unsigned char`. Contrast:

```
int a[2] = {0x12345678, 0x9abcdef0};
printf("addr = %p and content = %x\n", (unsigned char*)(&a) + 1, *((unsigned char*)(&a) + 1));
printf("addr = %p and content = %x\n", (&a) + 1, *((&a) + 1));
```

This is well-defined (but with an implementation-defined value since it depends on the platform's endianness) provided that `int` consists of at least two bytes (which is not strictly mandatory in C, but is the case everywhere except in a few embedded systems).

`(void*)(&a) + 1` is not standard C, because `void` doesn't have a size so it doesn't make sense to move a pointer to `void` one `void` element further. However some implementations such as GCC treat `void*` as byte pointers, just like `unsigned char *`, so adding an integer to a `void*` adds this integer to the address stored in the pointer.

¹  <sub>Or to `unsigned int` if the smaller type doesn't fit in a signed `int`, e.g. on a platform where `short` and `int` have the same size.</sub>

Comment: As long as OP switches to `unsigned char`, I don't believe there will be any problems with using the `%x` formatter. It will be promoted, but won't affect the value since they're both unsigned.

Comment: unsigned char will be promoted to a **signed int** on almost all platforms. Not that it should matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print bytes, then play with bytes:

- use `unsigned char*` or `uint8_t*` for pointers
- use %hhx to tell printf that input value is character length.

Example:

```
int a = 0x12345678;

printf("addr = %p and content = %hhx\n", (void*)&a,     *(uint8_t*)&a);
printf("addr = %p and content = %hhx\n", ((void*)&a)+1, *((uint8_t*)&a+1));
```

Result in my little-endian env:

```
addr = 0xbedbacac and content = 78
addr = 0xbedbacad and content = 56
```

And don't forget to use `*((uint8_t*)&a+1)` instead of `*(uint8_t*)&a+1`. In the example  the later would return 79  (78+1).